# cudaMalloc failing for 2D array, error code 11

Tags: c, arrays, cuda, nvidia

I'm attemping to implement a 2D array in CUDA as follows:

```
u_int32_t **device_fb = 0;
u_int32_t **host_fb = 0;

cudaMalloc((void **)&device_fb, (block_size*grid_size)*sizeof(u_int32_t*));

for(int i=0; i<(block_size*grid_size); i++)
{
    cudaMalloc((void **)&host_fb[i], numOpsPerCore*sizeof(u_int32_t));
}
cudaMemcpy(device_fb, host_fb, (block_size*grid_size)*sizeof(u_int32_t*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

On testing, `host_fb` is NULL. In addition, when I grab the error code for the first iteration of `cudaMalloc((void **)&host_fb[i], numOpsPerCore*sizeof(u_int32_t));` I get `cudaErrorInvalidValue`. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are a few problems with your code. Look at the comments in the code below.

In the size of the array, you should use `sizeof(u_int32_t)` and not a pointer type.
There are hard to find errors, because the size of the two types can be accidentally the same on some platforms, but not on others.

```
size_t arr_size = (block_size*grid_size) * sizeof(u_int32_t);

// host array wasn't allocated at all.
host_fb = malloc(arr_size);
cudaMalloc((void **)&device_fb, arr_size);

// the loop is unnecessary, you have now an allocated 2D table    

cudaMemcpy(device_fb, host_fb, (block_size*grid_size)*sizeof(u_int32_t*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

I used `malloc` function, because `cudaMallocHost` and `cudaHostAlloc` both allocate page-locked host memory accessible to the device, which isn't probably what you want here. You can use them if there is a performance problem, since both of them force the allocated memory to be paged. See the respective docs for details.

Comment: I tried your code, but I think I still need the loop on `host_fb` otherwise I get a bus error when trying to access `host_fb[0]` later on. I added the loop back in (along with a few of your changes) and it appears to have worked, but I'm not sure if it's correct.

Comment: What do you mean by bus error? When do you get it? Wasn't it cudaErrorInvalidValue (error code 11) what you got before?

Comment: Yeah previously the error was on the cudaMalloc (error code 11). Now when I try to run it in cuda-gdb, it gets a bus error and says it could not access the memory at `host_fb[0][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

The 2D arrays on GPU are tricky to manipulate, you have to take into account that GPU and CPU address space is incompatible. Let me point out a few observations:

1) You don't initialize the **host_fb array in the first place, so the subsequent calls the the elements of this array in the for-cycle are errorneous.

2) You should use cudaMallocHost (or something similar) to allocate memory that will be accessed by CPU

Other than that I can't help you, as you haven't told us what the code is supposed to accomplish.